# Property map is missing in String Flowtype

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Flowtype for array shows error.

```
type Props = {
  movies?: Array<any>
}

render() {
    const { movies } = this.props;

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <main className="moviedata-container"> {
          movies.map(movie => <MovieItem key={movie.id} movieItem={movie} />)
         }
        </main>
    </React.Fragment>
);
}
```

Error:

> Cannot call movies.map because property map is missing in String [1]

Comment: Are you sure movies is destructed from props? Could it be that you defined `movies` separately by mistake as string? What happens when you print `movies`?

Comment: @IssaShabo Yes 100%. I can see data. Edited question

Comment: This behaviour is really strange... What is your version of flow ? What type argument did you pass to React.Component ?

Comment: @debel27 `"flow-bin": "^0.92.0"` and `React.Component<Props>`

Answer (score 2):

Your type annotation indicates that the `movies` props could be `undefined`. You have to check that before being able to call `.map()`.

Yet, I see no reason why the error is talking about `String`...

The [reproduced example here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amAAKzbBQC8YAN6owYTHABu6amQD8ALjABBPHhKCAPCQB2ggHyoAvvzoxyFALKCAws7IVqADwJqCwATChp6AgA6DxZcCyCCUwk4KWsFJU4Q6jwACgBKeUUlYro4CzIiOWU1DQo7MFkCAAt0MkjsSTI+IuKwTgIAVzwLMBye4tNwhkiAMWMAc0wE217V00wSdBGnFwA5EiXpACIVdWpgkgISAFpSiyut7KPrMHHVpXT399PasAAyP7VM5tDbYHI-UTSF6mVw1agASUCrAA1tRBNI5BDIuhgvUIYjqJgMRD6sBrHk3u8HF8JsANlsVmtgFMonMSItlkU8nwlA4HKgoAMLAx0GUwLCzgTMDkOikyHpMXCpXpLII7AUFABIfpDEYWAYwGB8OxAA) works just fine.

Comment: Reason is i am using `movies.length > 0` for check and i can't change it. https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amAAKzbBQC8YAN6owYTHABu6amQD8ALjABBPHhKCAPCQB2ggHyoAvvzoxyFALKCAws7IVqADwJqCwATChp6AgA6DxZcCyCCUwk4KWsFJU4Q6jwACgBKeUUlYro4CzIiOWU1DQo7MFkCAAt0MkjsSTI+IuKwTgIAVzwLMBye4tNwhkiAMWMAc0wE217V00wSdBGnFwA5EiXpACIVdWpgkgISAFpSiyut7KPrMHHVpXT399PayJgg+bNMAvAAMYAAZODqmc2htsDkfqJpC9TK4atQAJKBVgAa2ogmkckRkXQwXqiKx1EwhMR9WA1jyb3eDi+E2AGy2KzWwCmUTmJEWyyKeT4SgcDlQUAGFgY6DKYDRZ0pmByHRSZD0RPRyr0lkEdgKCgAkP0hiMLAMYDA+HYgA :)

Comment: Why are you checking for `movies.length` ? Why can't you change it ? In order to be type safe, you must check for `movies` to be defined, not checking that it contains at least one element. Property `length` cannot be called on `undefined`

Comment: Because movies i got [] if there is nothing